# Hover behavior not taking effect in Android Webview

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview, chromebook

I have a webpage that has several css hover styles, using both the `:hover` pseudo selector and via the `cursor` property.  If I load this webpage in an embedded WebView on an Android device that has a mouse (e.g. Chromebooks), the CSS hover rules are not recognized.  The cursor is always the same and the hover highlighting never triggers.  Is there any way to enable this behavior?

Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webview );
        webview.loadUrl( "http://localserver/test.html" );
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="world.of.testapp.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

test.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #a:hover {
        color: red;
      }

      #b {
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="a">HELLO</div>
    <div id="b">WORLD</div>
  </body>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was a feature not yet implemented in Android and will be released soon: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=584424.